# Cdi constructor injection ejb

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

I downloaded intelliJ which gives me an advice to put my injections in a constructor. However when doing what they advice I have an other advice message telling me I need an empty constructor. So I'm wondering what's the best way to implement something like this :

That is just a background task in a jsf application that run every minute.

```
@Singleton
public class MatchesBgService implements Serializable {
    @Inject //intelliJmessage : Hey, you should use constructor injection
    private MatchLookup ml;
    @Inject
    private MatchTask bgTask;

    public MatchesBgService(){
        comparator = new MatchComparator();
    }

    @Schedule(hour = "*", minute = "*/1", second = "20", persistent = false)
    public void gettingMatches() {
```

Comment: @BalusC it was wrong import,not an architectural question.

Comment: @BalusC the information provided that it wasn't an architectural question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code might look like this:

```
@Singleton
public class MatchesBgService implements Serializable {

    private final MatchLookup ml;
    private final MatchTask bgTask;

    @Inject
    public MatchesBgService(MatchLookup ml, MatchTask bgTask){
        this.ml = ml;
        this.bgTask = bgTask;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answering your doubts:

1. It's considered a good practice to use a constructor injection wherever it makes sense.
2. CDI spec says you need a default empty constructor (to have class proxyable).
   But fortunately, at least Weld doesn't require it - so my above code will
   work just fine.

That is why IntelliJ gives you these advices.
Cheers

Comment: Had to change the import of singleton to not be the oine in ejb